# Open new window in main window pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to design second window opens when button clicked like in image but there are problem I can't understand it

```
class SubWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(673, 349)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored,QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.setWindowTitle("")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 638, 331))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame = QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"D:\project(AHR)\WhatsApp Image 2022-03-02 at 8.22.06 PM.jpeg"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.scrollArea_2 = QScrollArea(self.frame)
        self.scrollArea_2.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.scrollArea_2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 494, 63))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.setCentralWidget(self)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please provide more information on what the expected outcome is, what the actual behavior is and how it is different from what you expect and what else did you try to solve the problem

Comment: @Nechoj  problem is centralwidget not  take layout in main window